# Xcode NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to filter an array of objects like this:

```
{
    "id": "0",
    "title": "Crucifix and sarcophagus of Ariberto da Intimiano",
    "categoryName": "COMMEMORATIVE MONUMENTS",
    "audioFile": "Crucifix-and-sarcophagus-of-Ariberto-da-Intimiano",
    "videoFile": null,
    "textFile": "Crucifix-and-sarcophagus-of-Ariberto-da-Intimiano",
    "image": "content/0/Crucifix-and-sarcophagus-of-Ariberto-da-Intimiano_flow.jpg",
    "numPictures": "1",
    "didascalie": ["dida 1", "dida 2", "dida 3"],
    "description": "Crucifix and sarcophagus of Ariberto da Intimiano",
    "link": ""
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "The sundial of Duomo",
    "categoryName": "THE SUNDIAL",
    "audioFile": "The-sundial-of-Duomo",
    "videoFile": null,
    "textFile": "The-sundial-of-Duomo",
    "image": "content/1/The-sundial-of-Duomo_flow.jpg",
    "numPictures": "2",
    "didascalie": ["dida 1", "dida 2", "dida 3"],
    "description": "The sundial of Duomo",
    "link": ""
}


NSPredicate *key1Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == '%@'",_searchAZ.text];

    _ArtWorksTableResults = [[_ArtWorksTable filteredArrayUsingPredicate:key1Predicate] mutableCopy];

    NSLog(@"%i",_ArtWorksTableResults.count);
```

When I perform the search the `_ArtWorksTableResults.count` is always `0`.

But if I write the predicate instead of using the search bar text like this:

```
NSPredicate *key1Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == 'The sundial of duomo'"];

    _ArtWorksTableResults = [[_ArtWorksTable filteredArrayUsingPredicate:key1Predicate] mutableCopy];

    NSLog(@"%i",_ArtWorksTableResults.count);
```

The `_ArtWorksTableResults.count` is `1`, that is correct!

What I did wrong?

I try also to log the search bar text and everything is ok.

I can't understand why if I write the key of search directly in the code works!

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate format shouldn't have quotes in it when you're providing parameters:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@",_searchAZ.text];
```

Comment: Thank you! I remove quotes but the array is still empty when i perform the search! I'm getting crazy with it!

Comment: You probably want to use the string specific comparison so you can make it case insensitive (`LIKE[cd]`) instead of `==`.

Comment: Also check `_searchAZ` is actually connected.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html

No need for extra ' symbols, they are added by the formatter

At the end:

```
@"%K == '%@'"
This predicate checks whether the value of the key %K is equal to the string literal “%@“ (note the single quotes around %@). The key name %K is supplied at runtime as an argument to predicateWithFormat:.
```

Comment: Also, make sure _searchAZ is not nil

Comment: NSPredicate *key1Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(title like[cd] %@)",_searchAZ.text]; do you mean like this?